# Как сделать весь блок ссылкой?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, как сделать весь блок `div` ссылкой? А также применить к нему псевдоклассы `hover` и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
a span { display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #FF0; }
a:hover span { border: 1px solid #FF0000; }
</style>

<a href="/">
    <span>Click me</span>
</a>
```

Кроссбраузерно ли? Не смотрел!

Comment: работать будет, но семантически не верно

Comment: Нельзя внутри строчного элемента добавлять блочный.

Comment: @Gedweb, почему семантически неверно??

Comment: @Genson если я добавлю в него `<span>` и задам определенные css свойста это в корень изменит суть? Я могу апнуть ответ если `div` режит глаза!

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, читайте комментарий @Genson.

Если документ валиден, это еще не значит что он семантически корректен

Comment: Не режет, нормально, пусть будет:)

Comment: Сейчас, как раз, столкнулся именно с таким вариантом на [буржуйском сайте](http://www.bsnonline.net/) — в колонках товары, новости и события - сделаны `<a><div>...</div></a>`.

Comment: ну так проще жеж) и js не надо)

Comment: Нашел пожалуй самое простое решение - сделать display: block для ссылки и все! :) В этом случае блок и ссылка совмещаются в одном элементе, проблема решена.

Comment: Это класcика, особенно если верстаешь меню и элементам списка делаешь float, а ссылкам display:block.

Comment: @Genson: так уж прямо и "нельзя внутри строчного элемента добавлять блочный"? http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Answer (score 2):

`div .mydiv:hover`? в css
`$("div.mydiv).click()`? в js

Comment: Спасибо. На hover реагирует, ссылки пока нет. Js, это куда ставить?

Comment: куда-нибудь в страничку, не? :) я телепатию в школе не прощожил, уж извините)

Answer (score 2):

Просто меняешь `DIV` на `A` со стилем `display:block`

```
<div class="my-block">
   ...
</div>
```

меняешь на

```
<a class="my-block" href="#">
   ...
</a>

.my-block {
   display: block;
}
.my-block:hover {
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery код

```
var target='.block';

jQuery(target).each(function(){
    jQuery(this).click(function(){
        location = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');});
    jQuery(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});
```

И HTML

```
<div class="block">
     <a href="/" title="Ссылка">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='content'>
  <a href='#link'>
    <div> 
      <p>длинный текст</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.content {
  display:  block;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div.content > a {
  display:  block;
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.content > a div {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #543454;
}

div.content > a div p {
  color: #543454;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6dgzj811/